# Get-Content error: "Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null."

Tags: powershell

I've found this function that I use to get the full path to a file:

```
Function Get-Filename($initialDirectory="")

{

    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName(“System.windows.forms”) | Out-Null
 
    $OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
    $OpenFileDialog.initialDirectory = $initialdirectory
    # $OpenFileDialog.filter = "TXT (*.txt)| *.txt"
    $OpenFileDialog.ShowHelp = $true
    $OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() | out-null
    $OpenFileDialog.filename
  
    return $filnavn 
}

$InputFil = Get-FileName

$InputFil

$OurFilesData = Get-Content $InputFil -Encoding UTF8
```

I get this error message:

```
Get-Content : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At line:27 char:29
+ $OurFilesData = Get-Content $InputFil -Encoding UTF8
+                             ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-Content], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand
```

**What I know / has tried:**

- I'm running the code locally on my own machine
- $InputFil returns the correct full path and filename (example: C:\Temp\E-Drevet_KANALNAVNE.CSV)
- If it set the $InputFil variable manually ($InputFil = "C:\Temp\E-Drevet_KANALNAVNE.CSV") I don't get the same error
- Power Shell Version 5.1.19041.546

Why do I get this error when the input seems to be the same as when I manually set the $InputFil variable?

Comment: Did you tried `Get-Content -Path $InputFil`?

Comment: The error in your post doesn't seem to match the title, can you double check and clarify?

Comment: Remove `return $filnavn`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is thrown because *one of* the elements in `$InputFil` is `$null`.

Let's take a look at the last two statements in the function:

```
    $OpenFileDialog.filename
  
    return $filnavn
```

PowerShell outputs *everything*, not just whatever expression follows the `return` statement - so here, PowerShell first outputs the string value of `$OpenFileDialog.filename`, and then it subsequently outputs `$filnavn` - but `$filnavn` it never assigned to, so it resolve to `$null`.

The result is that `$InputFil` now holds an *array*, basically `$InputFil = @("C:\actual\file\path.ext",$null)`

Change your function definition to:

```
function Get-Filename($initialDirectory="")
{

    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName(“System.windows.forms”) | Out-Null
 
    $OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
    $OpenFileDialog.initialDirectory = $initialdirectory
    # $OpenFileDialog.filter = "TXT (*.txt)| *.txt"
    $OpenFileDialog.ShowHelp = $true

    if($OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() -eq 'OK'){
      return $OpenFileDialog.filename
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked like a champ. Thank you so much. I've upvoted you, but since I'm new it's not visible (?!?)

Comment: @RobertGrøndahlWinther That's great, you're welcome! FWIW you need at least 15 rep to upvote, don't sweat it :)

Comment: Upvote by proxy at your service. Have a great day. :)